# Display JSON Object held in Localstorage

Tags: jquery, json, html, local-storage, local

I am trying to retrieve a JSON object from localstorage in the web browser, and then display the values. I am able to save the JSON object, and push/ append new data to it. I am having difficulties figuring out the logic needed to retrieve and display it. To give a little background, variable "S" is a number that always changes. Time, is the time that the click (main function) happened. I want these two things paired together.

```
EX. I would like to print:
123456 - Time: 2:04
54321 - Time : 3:15
```

Here is how I am saving, and pushing/appending:

```
$("#oico").click(function() {
var S = window.localStorage.getItem("_snum");
var myDate = new Date();
var theDate = (myDate.getMonth()+1) + '.' + (myDate.getDate()) + '.' +     myDate.getFullYear();
var today = new Date();
var h = today.getHours();
var m = today.getMinutes();
var s = today.getSeconds();
var time = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
var obj = {};
obj[S] = time;
if (window.localStorage.getItem("_obj") === null) {
window.localStorage.setItem("_obj", JSON.stringify(obj));
} else {
    var existingEntries = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("_obj")) || [];;
    entry[S] = time;
    window.localStorage.setItem("entry", JSON.stringify(entry));
    // Save allEntries back to local storage
    existingEntries.push(entry);
    window.localStorage.setItem("_obj", JSON.stringify(existingEntries));
}
});
```

I am trying to figure out a way to print a list of all S properties in the object "_obj". However, since S is not a constant value/key, I can't figure out how to print all "S" properties in a list with their respective time values. I know my logic on how this is constructed is probably flawed, which is why I would like assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you iterate with a for loop through your object. Like this, you will get all keys and do not need to know their name in advance:

```
for (key in _obj) {

    alert("The current snum is: " + key);
    alert("Stored under the snum is: " + _obj[key]);

    if (key.match(/[0-9]+/)) {
       alert("Key is only numeric. It must be an snum.");
    }
}
```

In Javascript, your object properties may be any numeric value:

```
var obj = {
  1 : 'A',
  100 : 'B',
  42 : 'C'
};

for (key in obj) {
  alert ("Key: " + key + " val: " + obj[key]);
}
```

**EDIT 14/19/07**

I think you are confusing where and why you have an object or a primitive value.

If you only wish to enter a single value like a time to the storage, it is not necessary to make an object and a json from the value. So if you have a name in `S` and a `time` to store, then just write:

```
window.localStorage.setItem(S, time);
```

Then, as the localStorage is an object, you may just iterate through the key value pairs of the storage and find all numbers and times:

```
for(key in window.localStorage){
  val = localStorage.getItem(key); 
  alert("Number: " + key + " time: " + val);
}
```

But *if* you intend to create an object and to store it as json, then you should choose a unique name for the object, store it, later read and alter it at store it again by the unique name. Like this:

```
// Read the object to be added a new property
var myObjectJson = window.localStorage.getItem("MyObjectXY");
var myObject = JSON.parse(myObjectJson);

// Add a new key value pair
myObject[S] = time; 

// Store the object
window.localStorage.setItem("MyObjectXY", JSON.stringify(myObject));
```

If you work like this, you want to iterate through the object, not through the storage items.

In order to get a clearer sight, here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mjPDr/). It simply allows to store key value pairs.

In order to avoid local storage namespace pollution, I recommend the second method, storing an object. Namespace pollution leads to bugs difficult to find.

Comment: After turning this into a function:

Comment: function displayValues()
{
   for (key in _srtobj2) {

    alert("The current snum is: " + key);
    alert("Stored under the snum is: " + _srtobj2[key]);

    if (key.match(/[0-9]+/) {
       alert("Key is only numeric. It must be an snum.");
    }
}
}
displayValues(); I get the error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Comment: I forgot the second closing parenthesis in the if statement. I've edited the answer.

Comment: I am unsure what is wrong, but when I try making obj = window.localstorage.getItem("_obj"); and then trying to second set of code that you posted, it only printed this: Key: 82 val ]. Shouldn't the key have ex. 12345 and the value be ex. 3:05:01?

Comment: I cannot do your debugging work for you :-) just keep on it, you'll find out. Try to set a breakpoint in the debug console and to inspect the obj: what was really stored, and what was loaded? Or, try to alert a full json description of obj to understand what is really there. The for loop simply iterates, nothing more. Most browsers let you inspect local storages directly, btw.

Comment: I don't expect you to do any debugging. Just trying to understand and figure out the correct syntax/logic. I can see the local storage. _obj content is [{"64080":"12:12:2"},{"69032":"12:17:34"},{"s":"64530","st":"14:13:53"}]. Do you know if there are any illegal characters in that string or if it is somehow structured wrong?

Comment: This is syntactically correct. This is an array containing 3 objects. The first and sec. each have 1 property with a pure numerical name. The third has two properties, "s" and "st". If you wish to analyse/test json, use an online parser, e.g http://json.parser.online.fr

Comment: Okay, so if that is correct, then my logic must be wrong. In your solution you mention key, and storage. Now the storage "key" name is _obj according to the web browser. However, the key coming from alerts or that is printing in html is numerical. The value inside the "key"/storage _obj is the array. I am not sure I understand why when I setup the code I am getting numerics for key, and one character like "]" for the value. I am pretty sure I am doing something incorrect. Could you please explain further?

Comment: I understand that this may be confusing, so I've edited my answer in order to point out some aspects.